# Migration to AndroidX through update to Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android, androidx, android-studio-3.2

I am trying to migrate to AndroidX in order to use Material components as buttons, textInputLayout with OutputLines, etc. The thing is that, if I am not wrong, as it says on the official site, first I have to download Android 3.2. I already downloaded the 3.2 Beta 5, then I udpdated the compileSdkVersion from 26 to 28, I added the dependency
***implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'*** and changed the classpath from 3.1.3 to ***classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha13'***. 
When I click on Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX, I proceed to refactor and I get the following error:

[image]

I cannot find a way to migrate and use it... could you help me, please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `minSdk` and `targetSdk` from manifest and add them in app's gradle like this.

```
android {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
}
```

Also make sure you have `google()` defined in project's gradle file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```